# How to set response time out in Apache

Tags: apache

My Apache server giving me 503 for some response after 24 sec.
Is there any setting in Apache to configured response time out?
I have already configured connection_pool_timeout=600

My Apache redirect request to my application server. Now I am receiving 503 for application response. So is there any setting to increase response timeout?

Comment: What are you requesting?

Comment: Yes: it's called timeout. Apache on it's own will only serve static content - which is unlikely to time out - implying you've got a logic tier and a whole load more things which will have timeouts, including whatever connects Apache to the logic tier. But you didn't provide any details of these.

Comment: I have edit question. Please let me know if you want more info?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your setup there are different timeout options you can set (see [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)).
If you want a fast solution you could set `TimeOut` (see [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout)); `ProxyTimeout` and other timeouts will use `TimeOut` as default.

Example: `TimeOut 30` -- set default timeout to 30 seconds.